# CCControlButton's Title not show in cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x

When I use the following code to get the title in my button, my button does not show its title, just a blank button. How can I fix this code?

```
resumeBtn->setTitleForState(CCString::create(stringResource->getString("resume")->getCString()), CCControlStateNormal);
resumeBtn->setTitleForState(CCString::create(stringResource->getString("resume")->getCString()), CCControlStateHighlighted);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I create this button by CocosBuilder. It's a CCControlButton with "Resume" title and i use a String.plist that contains "resume" key with value is "Resume".

Comment: What does the rest of the code look like @Nikel

Comment: Have you made sure that the title's font colour isn't the same as the background colour? E.g. `resumeBtn->setTitleColorForState(ccBLACK, CCControlStateNormal);`